# IndentationError: unexpected indent...FRUSTRATING

Tags: python

I'm very new at Python scripting and am working on a script to turn on a fan when my Raspberry Pi3 reaches a specific temp.  I've been trying to debug my code all day and found I can't figure out what's wrong.  Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import signal
import subprocess
import atexit
import time
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pin = 18
maxTMP = 60

def setup():
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
 GPIO.setwarnings(False)
 return()

def setPin(mode):
 GPIO.output(pin, mode)
 return()

def exit_handler():
 GPIO.cleanup()

def FanON():
 SetPin(True)
 return()

def FanOFF():
 SetPin(False)
 return()

try:
 setup()
  while True:
   process = subprocess.Popen('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp',stdout = 
   subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
   temp,err = process.communicate()
   temp = str(temp).replace("temp=","")
   temp = str(temp).replace("\'C\n","")
   temp = float(temp)
  if temp>maxTMP:
   FanON()
  else:
   FanOFF()
   sleep(5)

finally:
 exit_handler()
```

Here is my error:

File "/home/pi/Scripts/run-fan.py", line 36
    while True:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

I've tried to indent every way possible.  I need help.

Thanks!

Comment: I think `setup()` and `while True` are not aligned. May be it should start from same point. Try one backspace in `while True` to see if error changes or it works.

Comment: If you use a larger indent (4 is usual). It will be easier for you to spot where your indentation is off.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says line 36 is indented too much. Everything after `setup()` is indented one level too far. Also `return` isn't a function call. Don't include the parentheses after it. (replace `return()` with `return`).

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 0):

I want to preface this with, you should use four spaces for your indentation. If you do, it will be way, way easier to see problems like the one you have here. If you use an IDE like Spyder or PyCharm, there are settings that automatically highlight indentation problems for you (regardless of how many spaces you want to use).

That said, with your current indentation scheme of one-space-per-indent, you want to replace your bottom block with this:

```
try:
 setup()
 while True:
  process = subprocess.Popen('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp',stdout =
  subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
  temp,err = process.communicate()
  temp = str(temp).replace("temp=","")
  temp = str(temp).replace("\'C\n","")
  temp = float(temp)
 if temp>maxTMP:
  FanON()
 else:
  FanOFF()
  sleep(5)
```

If you used four spaces instead of one on your original code, it would have looked like this:

```
try:
    setup()
        while True:
            process = subprocess.Popen('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp',stdout = 
            subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
            temp,err = process.communicate()
            temp = str(temp).replace("temp=","")
            temp = str(temp).replace("\'C\n","")
            temp = float(temp)
        if temp>maxTMP:
            FanON()
        else:
            FanOFF()
            sleep(5)
```

There's another problem here, which is that your `while True` block will currently never exit (maybe you want a `break` statement somewhere).